# how to execute an exe during wix install

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.7

```
<CustomAction Id="RegisterEXE" Directory="INSTALLDIR" ExeCommand="&quot;INSTALLDIR]MyApp.exe&quot; /Register" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />   
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='RegisterEXE' After='InstallFinalize' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I have used this code
But it does not execute the exe. Exe register itself as ole server and perform few other tasks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use this

```
<CustomAction Id="RegisterEXE"
                  Directory="INSTALLDIR"
                  ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]TKW5.exe&quot; /Register"
                  Execute="deferred"
                  Return="ignore"  
                  Impersonate="no"
                 />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='RegisterEXE' After='InstallFiles' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: For anyone out there if this does not work try setting CustomAction/@Execute to immediate as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585918/wix-install-error-2762-while-invoking-a-customaction-from-dialog/8587072

Comment: May be obvious to some - but I had to place this inside the <Product> element - otherwise it was ignored as I was putting it in a fragment which wasn't referenced anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why is the [INSTALLDIR] required for the ExeCommand when it is already set for the Directory?

Comment: @JK82 [INSTALLDIR] is used in the ExeCommand to provide the full path to the executable, while the Directory attribute sets the working directory for the custom action itself. This ensures that the custom action runs in the correct directory, and the executable is invoked with the correct path